# iOS вывести диалог при нажатии на уведомление

Tags: ios, push, dialog

в iOS не силен ещё, буду благодарен за пример/подсказку. Задача - когда приходит push уведомление, при нажатии на него открывается приложение. Нужно реализовать чтобы при нажатии на уведомление появлялся диалог, а уже при нажатии в нем нужной кнопки - запускалось приложение. Вот не могу осилить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открытие приложения при нажатии на баннер - стандартное поведение системы.
Можно при попытке открыть приложение сразу его закрывать, но помнится, что из-за подобного отклоняли публикацию.

Можно добавить `notification actions` и вот тут уже что-нибудь делать.

Либо кастомизировать с `notification extension`, но все-равно от стандартного поведения не уйти.

Comment: Т.е. избежать открытия приложения не удастся?.. Тогда вижу только путь скрывать основной визуальный компонент, и поверх прозрачного окна приложения выводить диалог.. Изврат  это конечно. На андроиде реализовал, диалог по нажатию на уведомление, думал что тут тоже так можно..

Comment: @Alexander , iOS немного отличается. Как говорится, раз нельзя победить - возглавь. По гайдлайнам и стандартному поведению подогнать под нужды и органично вписать в рамки.